# How to choose model parameters based on ACF and PACF in SARIMA model?

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, acf-pacf, differencing

I have some monthly data which show the number of visitors to a country whose plot is given below

[image]

Since there seems a non-constant variance, I took the log, which stabilized the variance.

[image]

To remove seasonality, I took the seasonal difference (D=1), which led to the plot below:

[image]

Next, I took regular the difference (d=1) to remove trend.

[image]

I tried a couple of models and chose the one with the lowest AIC, that is ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,1)12. However, the model's plots seem to violate the models assumption. The Q-Q plot and p values for Ljung p statistics do not seem OK to me.

[image]

This is where I have to stop since I am not very good at determining the p and q parameters based on ACF and PACF. So, can you please help me to get possible p,q, P and Q values? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You took both regular and seasonal differences. Did you check that the time series actually has both a simple and a seasonal unit root? (A quick visual inspection does not show signs of either, at least as far as I can tell.) If not, think carefully before applying differencing (simple or seasonal).

Comment: I applied KPSS test for simple unit root, which yielded a p value 0.01. After taking simple differencing,  I applied KPSS test again and this time I got a p value of 0.1, which means it is now stationary. For seasonal unit test, I applied OCSB test, but it does not produce a p value. Instead, it produces a test statistics of -20.5 and a critical value of -1.8. As far as I am concerned, this means that the seasonally differenced data are now stationary. So, do you have any suggestions for p, q, P and Q?

Comment: Well, I think the unit root tests are mistaken, perhaps because they ignore the trend or the seasonality. I would not difference in a simple or a seasonal way to begin with, so I do not find it all that meaningful to analyze differenced data. Thus I do not have suggestions for p, q, P or Q.